# How to call next assembly in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb

In gdb if I type `n` ,the next c statement will be run.

But how to instruct it to run the next assembly statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By typing nexti (ni) and stepi (si) instead of next (n) and step (s).